# Redirect to current friendly URL (with url variables or not)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a scenario where the website user have a filter-bar, to set what content they want to see on the website. After selecting the options the user clicks on the .net submit linkbutton.

The problem is that I want to reload that current page, but I am using **Friendly Urls**, `Intelligencia.UrlRewriter`, so I can't use :

`Request.Url` or `Request.ServerVariables.Get("PATH_INFO");`

I have managed to use `Request.UrlReferrer` , but this may occur `null` in some cases (even though I am checking for null I don't want to use this solution).

Is there some unique/specific way of solving my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Request.RawUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx) to get the original url. (The one the user sees in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:  `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL");`
I don't know about Intelligencia.UrlRewriter but it works with helicon ISAPI_Rewrite http://www.isapirewrite.com/